# Define a Global variable in jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Defining a Global variable in JavaScript/jQuery and getting it later in script.

But strange it is not working.

printing   `getResult` in console giving me `undefined`.

but when trying to print `getResult` just after the assigned value to it, it is giving me accurate value.

**Actually i need ajax result at the bottom .. how could i do this..?**

```
var getResult;
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    //JS statement to Ajax
    //JS statement to Ajax  
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: urlTo,
        data: dataSend,
        success: function (result, status) {
                getResult = result; 
                console.log(getResult); // getResult is working here
        }
    });

    //JS statement to Ajax
    //JS statement to Ajax  
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: urlTo2,
        data: dataSend2,
        success: function (result2, status) {

        }
    });

    console.log(getResult); // getResult is not working here. Giving " undefined" result here.
});
```

Comment: ok fine. i understand what i am doing.. i need ajax result at the bottom .. how could i do this..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JavaScript** is *synchronous*. **AJAX** is *asynchronous*.

Therefore, the `console.log(getResult);` at the bottom is firing before the following AJAX executes:

```
success: function (result, status) {
    getResult = result; 
    console.log(getResult); // getResult is working here
}
```

You can give `getResult` a default value and test it yourself.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"i need ajax result at the bottom"*? Are you wanting it in the 2nd AJAX success function? Are you trying to do something after both AJAX calls are completed? What?

Comment: Actually i want to store ajax result in variable and then want to use for other purpose.. we can say i want use these ajax result to pass to Template using Underscore.js

Comment: Ok, well like I said.  JavaScript is synchronous, so you can't just assume your asynchronous AJAX will have returned by the time you get to the bottom.  So, typically, what you have to do is call a function from inside your AJAX success function and that function will use the global variable you set.

Answer (score 4):

That is because `getResult` is not defined until the AJAX call is done, it is only **declared**.

Since AJAX is async, your first console log is like that :

```
var getResult;
console.log(getResult);
```

Can you give me the value of `getResult` here? No, because it is undefined (well actually its value is `undefined`, *shhh*)

Comment: ok fine. i understand what i am doing.. i need ajax result at the bottom .. how could i do this..?

Comment: You could use a function to do something with your value : http://jsfiddle.net/3Fe8Q/3/

Answer (score 1):

On the second AJAX call, you did not assign `getResult = result2;` causing `"undefined"` value.

Also, put the global `var = getResult;` inside the `getJSON` function.